# Angular 2 : How to set-up a @Input for an inline style?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that needs to display random values, which will be randomly generated and pushed in trough some **[`@Input`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child)** bindings troughout the template. So far so good, but I can't seem to link an `@Input` to a style image url like so:

`<a routerLink="{{nextLink}}" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link next" style="background: url('assets/images/{{nextBg}}');">`

Where `{{nextBg}}` would be a file with its extension e.g. `next.jpg` => ***this is what I am aiming for.***

I tried using `[ngStyle]` and `[style.background-image]` but without luck.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'prev-next',
    template: `
    <nav class="prev-next-nav">
        <a routerLink="{{prevLink}}" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link prev" style="background: url('assets/images/tesla.jpg');">
            <span class="link-dir">Previous project</span>
            <span class="link-title"><i class="icon icon-arrowright"></i>&nbsp;{{prevName}}</span>
        </a>
        <a routerLink="{{nextLink}}" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link next" style="background: url('assets/images/food.jpg');">
            <span class="link-dir">Next project</span>
            <span class="link-title">{{nextName}}&nbsp;<i class="icon icon-arrowright"></i></span>
        </a>
    </nav>
`
})

export class PrevNextComponent {
    // Previous link inputs
    @Input() prevBg: string;
    @Input() prevName: string;
    @Input() prevLink: string;

    // Next link inputs
    @Input() nextBg: string;
    @Input() nextName: string;
    @Input() nextLink: string;
}
```

Comment: What did you try with `[style.background-image]`? What didn't work?

Comment: I think you need the correct property binding syntax with `[ ]`, and can't use the string interpolation `{{}}` syntax here.  I would try something like `[style.background]="'assets/images/' + nextBg + "`. Don't know whether you need the url part, try it. The important things are: It's an expression where the static part is inside a string literal, denoted by single ' . And a dynamic part that gets added from the component object and is injected through `Input()`.

Comment: Using `[style.background-image]="'assets/images/' + nextBg + "` is putting out a `Unexpected end of expression` error, using `[style.background-image]="'assets/images/' + nextBg "`, without the last concatenation gives me a `WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value assets/images/nextBg.jpg` which seems to be reaching the image, but there goes that sanitizing stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following using `[ngStyle]`:

```
<a routerLink="{{prevLink}}" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link prev" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(assets/images/' + prevBg + ')'}">
    <span class="link-dir">Previous project</span>
    <span class="link-title"><i class="icon icon-arrowright"></i>&nbsp;{{prevName}}</span>
</a>
```

Or you could perhaps utilize the OnInit lifecycle hook to build out the URLs within the component that reference the `@Input() prevBg: string;`.

**HTML**

```
<a routerLink="{{prevLink}}" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link prev" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': prevBgUrl}">
    <span class="link-dir">Previous project</span>
    <span class="link-title"><i class="icon icon-arrowright"></i>&nbsp;{{prevName}}</span>
</a>
```

**TS**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.nextBgUrl = `url(assets/images/${this.nextBg})`;
}
```

I've created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2Jzf5dPvVqn6rMtOxLaq?p=preview). If you click on one of the hero's you'll see the placehold.it image being loaded in the `div.foo`. You should be load the local asset URL in the same say.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: First snippet did it. I was using `prevBg` with curly braces like so `[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(assets/images/' + {{prevBg}} + ')'}"`. Thank You very much!